# How to get an ubuntu workspace switcher that is always visible?

Tags: workspaces

I've probably asked this question before, but is there any way to get an Ubuntu workspace switcher that is always visible?

Obviously, I don't mean the full screen version.  I mean a small "thumbnail" version, that shows tiny representations of the existing windows, and gives you the ability to drag those "mini-windows" in the workspace switcher.

This isn't a new idea.  The old Solaris OpenWindows had this, and there have been a couple of applications on MS Windows that do this, like "sDesk" (there were two applications with this name) and "Dexpot", which is still actively maintained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways I know of to make switching worspaces easier and faster.

1. You can search for "cairo" dock in the ubuntu software center. This dock has a workspace switch applet which you can set to always be on top. I don't know if it supports dragging and dropping onto the applet.
2. Another way is pressing <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. On a windows keyboard this is <kbd>win-logo</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> or on a Mac press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to show all the virtual desktops. This way you can grab active windows and place them on the desktop of your liking. Double click on the desired workspace to zoom in to it.
3. Yet another way of switching between desktops is to hold <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd> followed by a directional key (<kbd>left</kbd>, <kbd>right</kbd>, <kbd>up</kbd>, <kbd>down</kbd>). You can drag active windows from one workspace to another by adding <kbd>shift</kbd> to that combination: <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> and a directional button.

Comment: The Cairo switcher is an improvement over what I had, so this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Unity has not such direct option. I think they consider it archaic. But there are ways how to run xfce, lxde or gnome desktop environments and those have it. Or you can run Xubuntu or Lubuntu.

For Ubuntu Unity 13.04, read this guide: http://kurtis319.blogspot.sk/2013/04/workspace-switcher-gone-after-upgrading.html

- Inistall unity tweak tool: `sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`
- Start it: `unity-tweak-tool` or via Unity dash
- Choose *Workspace Settings*
- Switch *Workspace switcher* to `ON`

In between the icons on the left you will see the Workspace switcher icon. But.. its not the same. I like the original way.